# Formatting 2021-12-26T00:00:00.000000Z in date-fns | reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date-fns

How can I format this date to a simple one? I am using date-fns as in my react project

```
2021-12-26T00:00:00.000000Z
```

Comment: What do you want the format to be?

Comment: @DevsiOdedra it returns .. RangeError: Invalid time value

Answer (score 1):

***Without using any third-party library***

Simple way for simple and readble format:

```
const date = new Date('2021-12-26T00:00:00.000000Z');
console.log({date});
// date: Sun Dec 26 2021 03:30:00
```

For more information, please read [this](https://javascript.info/date) article.

Comment: Please note that the answer doesn't use date-fns?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Would you really criticize a correct, short and simple solution using Vanilla.js instead of an unnecessary third-party library? For me, this is even an advantage.

Comment: @jabaa Not criticise. The OP asked for a solution using date-fns, that's all I wanted to bring attention to.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use as below.**

```
import { format } from 'date-fns 
format(new Date('2021-12-26T00:00:00.000000Z'), 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

Output will be:

> "2021-12-26"

Comment: it returns .. RangeError: Invalid time value

Comment: @Gurupalsingh its working fine, tested https://npm.runkit.com/date-fns